# Do AJAX functions have to be in the same file calling them?

Tags: php, ajax, html

I am able to call javascript functions from a JS file without any issues. When I move AJAX functions into the same file then the functions cannot be called. Do AJAX functions require that they are in the same file that they're called from?

**Home.html**

```
<button onclick=scale(id)>scale</button>
<button onclick=save(id)>Save</button>
```

**Javascript.js**

```
function scale(id){
 //scales the element with the given id
 //works
}
function save(id){
//Does not work unless in Home.html file
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "SaveValue.php?id="+id, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**SaveValue.php**

```
//Sends value to mysql db
```

-Update-
When I moved the AJAX function into a different JS file by itself, and linked it in the html file, everything worked.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Code is a little scattered so it took me a minute to gather the right snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript functions which perform Ajax options are no different from any other function as far as loading them is concerned.

There is no requirement to include the function inline in the HTML document.

You do, of course, still, need a `<script>` element to load them (or resort to things like fetching the script data with `XMLHttpRequest` and running it through `eval` — which is not recommended!).

---

If you have a problem, then it is most likely due to the `<script>` element failing to load the file. The most common reasons for this are revealed by the developer tools in your browser:

- The URL is wrong (the Network tab will tell you that you aren't getting a 200 OK response)
- The Content-Type is not `application/javascript` (or the legacy `text/javascript`). The Console will report an error and the Network tab will show the Content-Type.
- The HTML for the `<script>` element is wrong or in the wrong place (this will often be picked up by the use of a Markup Validator).

Comment: I looked into what the browser was flagging and it's saying the variable save() cannot be found. The function shrink(id) can still be called onclick but the save(id) function must not be loading correctly like you said. I might try linking another JS file with only the AJAX function to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: I moved the AJAX function into a different JS file and everything works now.